# How to “disable” 'redirect link' of Tumblr images

Tags: tumblr

I tried researching for a way to disable a redirect link of my Tumblr image posts, but can't seem to find one.

This is my problem, when I post an "Image Post", if you click on it in the main page will redirect the readers to the post URL, which is something like this: `http://xxxx.tumblr.com/post/297525140792343/imagepost` (just a sample).

What I want to do is that to disable this action, or, I don't want the image to be clickable into that URL. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove redirect link for Image posts (to disable previewing images bigger) then search for this in your Tumblr HTML code:

```
{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{Permalink}">{LinkCloseTag}
```

And replace it with this:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{Permalink}">
```

It worked perfectly fine for me!

Answer (score 3):

My theme was a little different, but I figured that all you need to do is search for (Cmnd/Cntrl F) these : `{LinkOpenTag}` and `{LinkCloseTag}` and remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your Tumblr theme. You'll need to go in your photo block and change/remove the url to `{Permalink}`